# How to use lazy_gettext with Pylons and setup.py

Tags: python, internationalization, pylons

Just a quick question. When I use the _() function provided by the Pylons i18n module, everything works just as expected.
My problem is with the lazy version of this function, lazy_gettext. When I run :

```
python setup.py extract_messages
```

I get in the POT file the strings to be translated with the _() function, but not those wuth lazy_gettext().
How may I get it to work ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the modules where you use `lazy_gettext()`, just assign `_ = lazy_gettext` and use `_()` instead.

Comment: Can't you just call `unicode()` against the ones you want to evaluate immediately?

Comment: Yep, thank you. But im my case, I need the two versions in the same module. I'll think about it.
I found another solution, which is to run `python setup.py extract_messages --keywords lazy_gettext` instead of the other one. But is there a "nicer" way to fix this ?

Comment: Yep, why not. Didn't think about this workaround.
It will do the job. Not really optimized through :)

Comment: I'm using Babel, but I think it's the same. In your code:`import lazy_gettext as _l`, and at extract time use `--keywords _l`. You can even add `import ngettext as _n`, and use `--keywords _n:1,2` (`--keywords` can be specified multiple times)